# How to group by date with Codeigniter active record?

Tags: codeigniter, datetime, date, group-by

I want to group the data in my blog table by date.

I have a datetime field in my database that I will use to group my data by month and year. ( example 2012-01-23 17:25:18 )

I have added the following code to my model in an attempt to group my data by month and year (like an archive)

```
function get_archive_links(){

        $this->db->order_by('date','desc');
        $this->db->group_by(Month('date'), Year('date')); 
        $query = $this->db->get('blog'); 

    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $data[] = array(
            'id' => $row->id,
            'date' => $row->date
        );
    }

    return $data;
}
```

But I receive the following error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function Month()`

Want the results to look like:

- February 2012
- January 2012
- December 2012

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this line,

```
$this->db->group_by(Month('date'), Year('date'));
```

Month is a PHP function at this line. If you want to use SQL MONTH and YEAR functions, this line must be like this:

```
$this->db->group_by('MONTH(date), YEAR(date)');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be

```
$this->db->group_by('date');
```

You can't run SQL functions via CI's activerecord unless you use the query method

```
$this->db->query("GROUP BY MONTH('date')");
```

Comment: That works kind of. But I get more than 1 result for each month. How can I show(January 2012, February 2012 etc) in archive format.

Comment: What does the table look like? are the months and years in separate columns?

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple try this in Active Record

```
$result = $this->db->select('DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(`t`.`date_field`, "%M %Y") `myformat`', FALSE)->from('my_table `t`')->group_by('MONTH(`t`.`date_field`)')->order_by('t.date_field', 'DESC')->get()->result();
print_r($result);
```

OR simple Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  DATE_FORMAT(`t`.`date_field`, "%M %Y") `myformat` 
FROM
  (`my_table` `t`) 
GROUP BY MONTH(`t`.`date_field`) 
ORDER BY `t`.`date_field` DESC;
```

Output printing array

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [myformat] => August 2011
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [myformat] => July 2011
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [myformat] => June 2011
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [myformat] => March 2011
    )
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks!!